# From Javascript Date.now to PHP date

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, date

I have an ajax request with "Date.now" parameter, and I need to transform that timestamp to PHP datetime.
I tried with:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('time'));
```

but the date I get is not the same of Js date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.now()` in Javascript returns a timestamp in milliseconds, whereas Carbon's `createFromTimestamp`method expects seconds.

There's a separate function you can use that accepts a millisecond-precision value. Try:

```
 $now = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($request->input('time'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Date.now()` returns the timestamp in milliseconds, but `createFromTimestamp()` accept timestamp in seconds.

Try to use

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($request->input('time'));
```

Or divide by 1000:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('time') / 1000);
```

Comment: @iainn Yes, 8 seconds differences, sorry. You were faster.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to use Timezone (change to your timezone).

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('time'),', 'Europe/London');
```

Example here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Also check this function `Carbon::createFromTimestampMs`, because Data.now() is not in seconds.